# Ask Mathematica to always print errors in InputForm

Tags: warning-messages, output-formatting

When using Mathematica on the terminal (as REPL or as script) the errors are formatted in this way:

```
                                                                                    -12                              Numerator
Some::message: Long error message that contains a number with an exponent such as 10     or, even worse, fractions -------------
                                                                                                                    Denominator
```

On the terminal, which by default wraps lines, this is rendered horribly:

```
                        -12                              Num
erator
Some::message: Long error message that contains a number wit
h an exponent such as 10     or, even worse, fractions -----
--------
                                                        Deno
minator
```

Is there a global option to make sure that errors are, by default, formatted in `InputForm`, so that the results are readable and also copy-pasteable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`$MessagePrePrint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$MessagePrePrint.html).

```
$MessagePrePrint = InputForm;
```

[image]